# Adding item into dict while iterating

Tags: python

How safe it is to add an item to dictionary while iterating that dictionary? It kinda works at first glance but I wonder if there might be cases when it's not safe.
The keys are strings `0`, `1`...etc.

Comment: If there are no side effects, try and use dictionary comprehension,

Comment: @thefourtheye could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Please show some code, without that suggesting is difficult :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the dictionnary's size while iterating:

```
>>> foo = {'spam': 'egg'}
>>> for i in foo:
...  foo['egg'] = 'spam'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

You have to first make a copy:

```
>>> foo = {'spam': 'egg'}
>>> for i in dict(foo):
...  foo['egg'] = 'spam'
... 
>>> foo
{'spam': 'egg', 'egg': 'spam'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using items() or keys() method it is safe to modify the dict. items() returns a copy of the dict key, value pairs and keys() returns a copy of the dict's keys.

```
>>> foo = {'spam': 'egg'}
>>> for k, v in foo.items():
...  foo['egg'] = 'spam'
```